# Invert child and parent view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When I go to a url like /**/details (e.g. /users/details, /accounts/details/ ...) i would like to show more or less the same components. When I go to a url like /**/list, i would like to show a different set of similar components of the child view. This means I would like to get the parent view inside the child view, instead of the child view inside the parent view.

Normally when you create a child state, the child should be contained in the parent. Like this:

app.html

```
<ui-view /><!-- users.html gets loaded here -->
```

users.html

```
Now we are in the users section
<ui-view /><!-- detail.html gets loaded here -->
```

user-detail.html

```
Now we are in the user detail section
User name : {{user.name}}
```

But is it possible to include in some way the parent (e.g. users) in the child (e.g. details)? It would make more sense, I think. Like this:

app.html

```
<ui-view /><!-- details.html gets loaded here -->
```

details.html

```
Now we are in the details section. I can show ui elements here that fit in every details section:
<menu-bar>
<button style="float:right">Add</button>
<ui-view> <!-- user-detail.html get loaded here -->
<a>Back to list</a>
```

user-detail.html

```
Now we are in the user detail section
User name : {{user.name}}
```

Is there a solution to achieve this? Until now I have used the following structure in app.html:

app.html

```
<div ng-if="details">
    <menu-bar>
    <button style="float:right">Add</button>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
    <a>Back to list</a>
</div>
<div ng-if="list">
    <filter-bar>
    <button style="float:right">Add</button>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

Technically this works, but it doesn't give nice transitions, and doesn't feel like the clean way to do it.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , specifically this part http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can access parent scope in child by `$scope.$parent`.  You have to provide more details in order to get more specified anwser.